# How to run an Identify task on a WMS layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms

I'm new to WMS layers, and am looking for a way to retrieve a layer's attributes when clicking on the map, using the ArcGIS Server JS API.

The documentation is a bit sparse, but from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/arcgis-server-wms-getfeatureinfo-tolerance) it appears that I'll need to construct a query using GetFeatureInfo.

Before I re-invent the wheel, has anyone written a wrapper function or sample code which builds the appropriate query when the user clicks on the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WMS GetFeatureInfo request is very similar to the GetMap request. There is an example [here](http://jpenet.blogspot.com/2012/05/arcgis-javascript-api-using-google.html) showing code sample for GetFeatureInfo.

Also, keep in mind, that the GetFeatureInfo is not "standardized", so depending on server vendor, the response is differently formatted. Expect to do some extra parsing/styling.

Comment: I ended up running a GetCapabilities, then using its values to run a GetFeatureInfo, with the height, width, extent and X/Y values calculated from the map on mouse click. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I've now run into a further problem if you have a chance to look: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69420/how-to-determine-the-accuracy-of-getfeatureinfo-on-a-wms-layer - thanks