# How to determine the accuracy of getFeatureInfo on a WMS layer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have added a WMS layer to the ArcGIS Server JSAPI and am attempting to query it using `getFeatureInfo` when the user clicks on the map.

This is mostly working, except that the accuracy of the results is very suspicious. If I click within a few hundred metres of a polygon boundary, I often get back the neighbouring polygon's results:

[image]

In this case I have clicked within Staffordshire Moorlands 010B (as shown by the infoWindow's anchor) but the result shows the neighbouring polygon 011C.

In order to run the `getFeatureInfo`, I am calculating the map extent in its native web mercator, converting this into the units of the WMS layer, and using this as the bounding box.

Is this a valid approach?

The question [ArcGIS Server WMS GetFeatureInfo tolerance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/arcgis-server-wms-getfeatureinfo-tolerance) implies that there may be some trickery required to get the tolerance right?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with pixel tolerance. Do you use the same extent as in the GetMap request ? (you should)

Comment: Just checking but are you including a transformation when you convert to the WMS layer's CRS (I assume it's 27700, BNG)?

Comment: @Oyvind I'm using "new esri.layers.WMSLayer()" to create the layer, so the JSAPI builds an automatic GetMap request each time the extent changes. Firebug shows that GetMap is using 102100 while GetFeatureInfo is using 4326. I'll investigate this further - thanks

Comment: @mkennedy I'm a little confused about transformations in the geometryService.project - can you give me an example? The [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/projectparameters-amd.html#transformation) is a bit vague in this area. Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the help too! If you are using 102100/4326, no transformation is needed. If there is a 27700 in the mix somewhere, try 1314, OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_6.

Comment: It would make it a lot easier if you updated your question with both the GetMap and the corresponding GetFeatureInfo url's. You don't need to transform anything, if you use the same SRS in both requests. The WIDTH, HEIGHT, BBOX and SRS must be identical in both requests.

Comment: @Oyvind I've added the new sample and links to the requests. Thanks

Comment: I tried your example again today in order to debug URL's, but seems like you removed the GetFeatureInfo code again..

Comment: Seems like the site sporadically stops working in Firefox.. but whatever, see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By extracting parameters while debugging your website, I found the following: The X and Y position is somewhat wrong.

The screenshot shows the info box where I clicked, and the red dot shows the actual X and Y position that is submitted in GetFeatureInfo. So it apparently looks like I clicked in the 010B polygon, but the submitted X and Y is actually inside 011C. So, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the server result here !

Perhaps the X and Y is relative to a wrong element or something like that ?

[image]

Comment: Bingo - I was using the [onClick](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#click) event's evt.screenX and .screenY - this is subtly different to evt.screenPoint.x (possibly a bug). Thanks!