# Why is ArcGIS Server 10.0 getFeatureInfo not being buffered?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, openlayers-2, arcgis-server, getfeatureinfo

Using AGS10.0 I have a point featureclass published as wms. In my Openlayers client, I am not able to click on the point and recieve the GetFeatureInfo response unless I hit the target very accurately. Strangely, when I zoom in to the point it is harder to hit than when the map is zoomed out in a smaller scale.

Does anyone have a trick to be able to buffer the GetFeatureInfo request so that a getFeatureInfo request becomes more user friendly?

For more context I have sent this post to the esri forum (http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/108479-Set-tolerance-for-ArcGIS-Sever-10.0-GetFeatureInfo-query?p=384651&ESRISessionID=__kafq_4ATGCzLXerP68fkOpCCGe1ttHoAcLV9s54Wb-36WXv_w_8fA7JLQQUYXtsZCVwQ==)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/arcgis-server-wms-getfeatureinfo-tolerance looks highly relevant - the main difference seems to be the use of OpenLayers as the WMS client here.

Comment: The problem with the referenced Post is that I don´t understand exactly what I am supposed to do! Reducing the resolution of the GetFeatureInfo request on-the-fly means what?...that I have to edit the request in Firebug and take off the last 4 digits?

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your Question to be more along the lines of "there is a possible solution to how to effectively increase the search tolerance described in another Question but this Question is about how to implement that using OpenLayers".  If there is ever another Question which looks like a possible duplicate floating around I think it is best to reference it early so that you can explain as background why it does not simply provide an Answer.

Comment: I don't find it odd that as you zoom in it gets harder to hit a point, what you are doing is having to be more and more accurate... when you zoom out there is a higher chance that one or more points will lie within a single pixel on the image.   I guess the answer will be don't allow a GetFeatureInfo request when zoomed in too far.  Then use the FEATURE_COUNT parameter set to some high value so you get more than the default one result returned.

Comment: An alternative possibility would be to reduce the resolution of the original GetMap image, in your GetFeatureInfo request, but do do that you will need to recalculate the pixel coordinates for the actual point queried.